# AlarmManager - how to set good repeat

Tags: java, alarmmanager

I'm writing the application and I want to send information to server in every 10 second. Firstly I was using the Timer and TimerTask, but it wasn't good choice because when I asleeped the device I wasn't work good. So now I want to try using AlarmManager but I have a problem when I want to set repeat

```
void startRepeatingSend() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainReceiver.class); // odbiornik
    intent.setAction("com.example.marcin.sbdintheroom.CYCLE");
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 5000, 5000, alarmIntent);
}
```

I set the intervalMillis on 5 seconds, but my receiver receive broadcast only one time per minute

Answer (score 0):

You can delay you application with Thread.sleep(miliseconds);

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // interupt thread when error
    // handle error
}
```